# Динамическое обновление таблицы информацией из базы данных MS SQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qlabel, qtimer

Есть окно программы, в котором выводится таблица заполненная информацией находящийся в БД.

Каким способом можно сделать динамическое изменение таблицы, при изменении информации в БД?

Как я понял, это делается по таймеру, то есть каждые **`n`** секунд мне надо вызывать `testTableRequest()`.

Попробовал сделать по простому:

```
    def testTableConnect(self):
        self.conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                              'Server=LAPTOP-M6O5U927;'
                              'Database=testBD;'
                              'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        while True:
            self.testTimer()

    def testTimer(self):
        self.testTableRequest()
        time.sleep(30)

    def testTableRequest(self):
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        request = 'SELECT * FROM testBD.dbo.firstTestTable'
        result = cursor.execute(request)

        labels = ['uid', 'name', 'value']
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(labels))
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)

        #self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().hide()

        self.array = []

        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(row_number+1)
            for col_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                if col_number == 2:
                    self.array.append(data)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, col_number,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
                    #print('value',row_number, col_number, data)
        self.plotTarget()
```

Но в таком случае зацикливается только на обновлении и окно программы не запускается.

---

Зашел почитать [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) и нашел там пример:

```
def hello():
    print("hello, world")

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start()  # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
```

В таком случае мне надо создать свой класс таймера и использовать его? Или где его найти?

---

Так же пробовал сделать через

```
    def testTimer(self):

        timer = threading.Timer(15.0, self.testTableRequest())
        timer.start()
```

Но в этом случае у меня просто постоянно обновлялись данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Класс `QTimer` предоставляет повторяющиеся и одиночные таймеры.
>
> `QTimer::timeout()`
>   Этот сигнал испускается, когда таймер истекает.
>
> Примечание: это частный сигнал. Он может использоваться в сигнальных соединениях, 
>   но не может излучаться пользователем.

Подробнее читаем здесь https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#reimplemented-protected-functions

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QTimer, QDateTime
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, \
    QTextEdit, QPushButton


class MyGui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.label = QLabel('time', self)
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.button = QPushButton('Старт')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onButton)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)                  # интервал времени ожидания в миллисекундах
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.displayTime)

    def displayTime(self):
        self.label.setText(QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString())
        self.textEdit.append('Hello World')

    def onButton(self):
        if self.button.text() == 'Старт':
            self.timer.start()                        # start
            self.button.setText('Стоп')
        else:
            self.timer.stop()                         # stop
            self.button.setText('Старт')           


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MyGui()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но возник такой вопрос, а рационально ли это? Мол обязательно ли мне по таймеру постоянно вызывать функцию и заново перестраивать график каждую секунду? Может быть есть какие то другие способы?

Comment: @Murph  Нужно ли вам обновляться и перерисовывать график - это видимо только вам известно.
Если все таки обновляться нужно, то вы должны понимать в результате каких событий 
это обновление надо делать или с какой периодичностью делать обновление.

Если ваше обновление не занимает много времени (интерфейс не замораживается), 
то таймер вам подходит. 
Если задача обновление - тяжелая, то вам надо делать обновление в отдельном потоке.

Answer (score -1):

Лучше всего вашу задачу можно решить с помощью стандартных библиотек schedule и time:

```
import schedule
import time
# тут ваша программа
if __name__ == "__main__": # если название файла не "main" тогда соотв. меняете тут и ниже название
    try:
        main()
        # здесь приведен пример обновления раз в минуту, но также вы можете использовать любые другие интервалы
        schedule.every().minute.do(main) 
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as ex: # здесь мы может захватывать ошибки, если необходимо
        print(ex)
        time.sleep(2)
```